# woocommerce product filter[q] getting invalid signature as a response

Tags: android, wordpress, filter, woocommerce

I have developed an woocommerce integrated android app. The issue is except filter everything working fine.
when i apply filter like, 
http://www.websitename.com/wc-api/v3/products?filter[q]=black 
or some other filter like filter[limit]=30 not working, always getting invalid signature as a response

i have found this

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/blob/master/source/includes/v3/_introduction.md

q- performs a keyword search and returns resources that match, e.g. GET /products?filter[q]=search-keyword. Note that search terms should be URL-encoded as they will be decoded internally with urldecode

But still don't no how to get worked q filter